# Insert Search Bootstrap component into the navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to insert this [bootstrap search component](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-navbar-search) into my navbar.

Here's the html of the search snippet:

```
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
                            <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/pen/VLoXjp?editors=110) with my code and here's the [full screen view](http://s.codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/debug/VLoXjp?#) of my navbar.

So, basically, when the search icon is clicked I need the whole navbar to become a search field (just like in the link with search snippet). But when I insert the search snippet into my navbar and try to click the search icon, not the whole navbar becomes a search field, just the halve of it.

I guess I'm doing something wrong with `collapse navbar-collapse` classes, I tried adding them to different dropdown elements on my navbar, to wrap the search form in those classes, but I didn't manage to make it work properly. There's also some jQuery code in the snippet which toggles the `.active` class and adds some `click` event listeners, but I assume it doesn't need any changes, I believe my issue is more about css and proper classes in html elements.

Could you please help me with inserting the search snippet correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the Bootstrap version. The Bootsnipp uses v 3.1, but your Codepen is using the newer 3.3.5. In the newer version, the CSS for `input-btn-group` has changed to `width:auto`.

If you want to use 3.3.5, add an override the set the width to 1%..

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn {
    width: 1%;
  }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/mtMcAYqmOz

Comment: For some reason, the `Symphony` link, the one with class `navbar-brand` on the very left of the navbar, stopped working, became unclickable. Do you have any ideas on what could happen and how to make it work?

Comment: It's supposed to have `href=` not `src=`

Comment: it's actually not about that, I changed that to `href` when noticed the bug, but it didn't change anything.